# What is the proper way to declare calculated fields in AngularJs' model?

Tags: angularjs

How should I declare calculated field in AngularJs model? If I do it like this:

```
 $scope.model = {
        id: null,
        calculatedField: function() {
            return 1+2;
        }
    };
```

and then send the whole object to web server like this:

```
$http.post(url, $scope.model)...
```

it always sends null for `calculatedField` field value. It seemingly expects properties, not functions while serializing the object to Json.

UPDATE: I want calculatedField() being automatically called every time the model is serialized in Json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `calculatedField` should behave like a value then just make it a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```
$scope.model = {
    id: null,
    get calculatedField() {
        return 1+2;
    }
};
```

You can use it like a regular value property except that you can't assign a value to it. Of course, it also gets serialized properly.

```
var x = $scope.model.calculatedField; // x = 3

$scope.model.calculatedField = 4; //doesn't change calculatedField

JSON.stringify($scope.model); // "{"id":null,"calculatedField":3}"
```

Getters are regular JavaScript btw.

Answer (score 1):

You've found a situation where JavaScript and Angular don't really provide an out-of-the-box. You're going to have to make some decisions on the best way of implementing this in your application.

The easiest way to control the serialisation of an object to JSON is by adding a [`toJSON()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior). This is just like the `toString()` method, but instead of returning the string representation you return the **object representation** that you want converted to JSON.

Here is an example for your model that will copy everything from the model to the return object. However, for every function it will output the result of calling that function:

```
$scope.model = {
    id: null,
    calculatedField: function() {
        return 1+2;
    },

    /**
     * Return an object that represents this model 
     * instance and will be converted to JSON.
     */
    toJSON: function(){
        var o = {};
        angular.forEach(this, function(value, key){
            if (angular.isFunction(value)){
                o[key] = value();
            } else {
                o[key] = value;
            }
        }, this);

        return o;
    }
};
```

JSON serialisation result:

```
console.log(angular.toJson($scope.model));

/*
{
    "id": null,
    "calculatedField": 3
}
*/
```

Note that the `toJSON()` method was called automatically when the object was serialised to JSON. This means you can't forget to call it before POSTing it to your server

The other good thing is if you have nested objects with `toJSON()` methods they will also be called all the way down the graph of objects.

This should give you a starting point to work out the best way of serialising your models.

From here you can tweak the `toJSON()` example above - i.e. if certain methods or properties should be excluded from the JSON output.

Here is an example of how you could filter out particular properties/functions:

```
$scope.model = {
    id: null,
    calculatedField: function() {
        return 1+2;
    },

    // Example function we don't want serialised at all.
    myNonCalculatedField: function(param1, param2){
        return param1 + param2;
    },

    /**
     * Return an object that represents this model 
     * instance and will be converted to JSON.
     */
    '@exclude': {
        '@exclude': false,
        'myNonCalculatedField': false
    },
    toJSON: function(){
        var o = {};

        var excludeMap = this['@exclude'];
        angular.forEach(this, function(value, key){
            // Skip any property that we've marked as excluded.
            if (excludeMap[key] === false){
                return;
            }

            // Copy everything else to the return object.
            if (angular.isFunction(value)){
                o[key] = value();
            } else {
                o[key] = value;
            }
        }, this);

        return o;
    }
};
```

Comment: Good to know, turns out be so easy to setup your own custom Json serialization. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular function instead of an anonymous function.

Ex.

```js
    var field = function(){
        return 1+2;
    }
   $scope.model = {
        id: null,
        calculatedField: field()
    };
```

Comment: it runs the function only once, and if you add something like count++ inside you will see it always returns initial value, while I want this function to be run every time its value is read

Comment: You could also populate the model field from within the function... `$scope.model.calculatedField = 1+2; ` You initialize the object only once, and then just update the corresponding field whenever that corresponding function is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFun = function() {
                return 1+2;
            };
```

In case you want to send the return value:

```
 $scope.model = {
        id: null,
        calculatedField: myFun()
    };
```

In case you want to send the definition of the function:

```
 $scope.model = {
        id: null,
        calculatedField: myFun.toString()// convert the function to string.
    };
```

Recalculate:

```
$scope.calculatedField = myFun();
$http.post(url, $scope.model)...
```

In JS, if you want something like auto update, you can use object preference:

```
var var_1 = {a: 123};
var var_2 = var_1;
var_1.a = 456;//change value 'a' in var_1.
console.log(var_2.a)//the value 'a' in var_2 is 456 also.
```

UPDATE: If you want calculatedField() being automatically called every time the model is changed, you can try $watch in angularjs:

```
$scope.$watch('modelToWatch', function(newVal, oldVal) {
calculatedField();
});
```

Comment: the problem is it run the function only once, if you add something like `count++` inside you will see it always returns initial value, while I want this function to be run every time its value is read

Comment: I know I can do that, but I have many such places where "fresh" value of calculated field needs to be taken, I though there might be a way to automate it like property getters work in .Net

Comment: Just call the function only one time before you post it to the server, dont care how many time it has been freshed before updating. Please see my edit.

Comment: This is the thing I'm trying to avoid: If I have dozens `$http.post(url, $scope.model)` each one with different url, I have to have dozens of `$scope.calculatedField = myFun();` too. If I forget to call myFun() before $http sometimes in the future I'll be in trouble

Comment: To me, I always create a function to wrap $http requets, put some handling in this before calling the real $http. Something like that: function myRequet(){ myFun(); ... $http.post(url, $scope.model);}, i just call myRequest() everywhere i want to use $http post, if i want to change some handling, i change it inside the myRequest function. And if you want something like auto update, please see my edit again.

Comment: calculatedField() returns some value from third-party control which I cannot modify, so calculatedField() value is changed not based on other model properties, but based on third-party control user interacts with. Sorry for misleading name 'calculatedField', I made such name up for the sake of simplicity, however actually it is just a function which does not depend on the rest of the model, but on user actions

Comment: You should create a directive to wrap that third-party. If you cannot controll that value in angularjs, you implement it the wrong way in angularjs.